# My Java GUI interfaces with my uber-cool proprietary dll. How can I prevent 3rd parties from interfacing with this dll?

Tags: java, c++, security, user-interface, linker

I'm writing my process in C++.
Now I want to write its GUI.
I was thinking of using Java in order to do this and link it using JNI, but then I thought of a security problem...
Suppose I have my GUI.exe file written in Java, and I also have my Engine.dll file written in c++.
What would prevent evil evil people from taking my DLL and linking it to their program?
I do use a license validation stuff in my C++ dll, but it can be broken by these evil evil people.
I know every program can be cracked, but I don't want to just GIVE them my engine for easy use.

Is there a way to secure this link?
Or should I use C++ for writing the GUI as well?

Comment: Well...nothing is really safe from Reverse Engineering your DLL, but if the people who supposedly get your DLL know exactly how you did it, then I can't really a security problem as such.

Comment: I'm not worried about reverse engineering. Suppose you have your DLL which exposes a function "DoSuperAmazingThing". I can take this DLL, link it to my program, call "DoSuperAmazingThing" and sell it with my program. Maybe i'll even use it as a lib, so you'll never know. <evil laugh>

Answer (score 0):

The most portable solution probably involves encrypting the data entering and leaving your DLL by whatever means seems appropriate. Obfuscation of the C++ side isn't necessary at that point. This would require the encryption keys to be embedded in both the C++ binary and whatever you are compiling your Java to; you could take extra steps to make this inconvenient to find by hiding it with a large slab of random junk and indexing into it, for example.

Another alternative is to pay up for a licensing system that would be checked at call or link time by ubercool.dll.

Ultimately you're trying to perform a bit of a doomed defensive action. If your ubercool function is genuinely valuable or useful and someone wants to use it in ways you'd rather they didn't, they'll work out how. Can anyone think of any commerical software that hasn't been cracked?

Lastly, you can run your software on a system which is impractical for the end user to fiddle with. Mobile devices with locked bootloaders, TPM modules and so on are one way to do this; the other is to run your ubercool stuff as a hosted service to which people may connect if they have appropriate credentials which you can of course control.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using obfuscator for your Java or C# code that will use your dll. This will not solve all the problem, but it will be more difficult to reverse engineere your programm.

Also, if your project is written in C++, you may consider using C++\CLI for your GUI part of application.

Comment: ok, but then again if I want to use your C++ DLL, I don't really care about your obfuscated C#/Java code.

Comment: I meant that obfuscation may hide some details that will help someone understand DLL.

Comment: As far as I know C++ obfuscation is doable only by trashing your source code, giving bad names to the exposed method in your release version, adding dummy methods, etc. I'd rather not do that. It may also not be very effective...

Comment: I'm talking not about C++ obfuscation, but about Java or C# or whatever he uses to represent GUI.

Comment: I have you engine.dll written in c++. I also have your super-encrypted-obfuscated-and-what-not gui.exe. I throw away your EXE, take the DLL and use it. whatcha gonna do 'bout it? ;)

Comment: Nothing. Not my problem, in this case. I think, there are ways of solving this problem, but I'm not familiar with them.